# Fourier series of a piecewise continuous linear $2π-periodic$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Problem: Show that the Fourier series of a piecewise continuous linear $2π-periodic$ function converges to this function uniformly. Here the function $f (x)$ continues on the segment [a, b] is called piecewise linear, if there is a partition of the segment [a, b] in a finite number of segments $[x_{i-1}, x_i]$,
$$a = x_0 < x_1 < · · · < x_i < · · · < x_{n−1} < x_n = b$$

such that the function $f (x)$ is linear over each of the segments $[x_{i-1}, x_i], i = 1, 2,. . . , n$

I don't understand how to test it.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

I'll firstly remind us of some common theorem.

**Lemma**
 Let $f$ be a $2\pi$-periodic measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f \in L^1[ -\pi,\pi]$.
Assume that $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f}(n)| <+\infty$$
then there is a continuous function $g$ such that $$ \sum_{|n| \le N} \hat{f}(n)e^{inx} \xrightarrow[N \rightarrow +\infty]{\text{uniformly}} g $$
and $g = f \quad \text{a.e}$
$\square$

In light of the above theorem, if we can prove that :$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} |\hat{f}(n)| <+\infty$$
Our work is done.

**Solution**

Let $g$ be the piecewise constant function which is deduced by the derivation of $f$, that is $f'(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$ except the points at which $f$ changes slope.
We have:
$$2\hat{f}(n) \underbrace{=}_{\text{periordicity}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}\left[ f(x)-f\left(x-\frac{\pi}{n}\right) \right] e^{-inx}dx \\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} \int_{-\pi/n}^{0} g(x+s)ds e^{-inx}dx\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\pi/n}^{0} \int_{[-\pi,\pi]}  g(x+s)dx e^{-inx}ds\\\underbrace{=}_{\text{periordicity}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\pi/n}^{0} \int_{[-\pi,\pi]}  g(x)dx e^{-inx+ins}ds\\ = \frac{-2i}{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}  g(x)e^{-inx}dx $$
Repeat what we've done  at the very first equality again, we have:
$$4 \hat{f}(n) =\frac{-2i}{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]} \left[ g(x) -g(x-\frac{\pi}{n})\right]e^{-inx}dx $$
Thus,
$$ |\hat{f}(n)| \le \frac{1}{2n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{[-\pi,\pi]} \underbrace{\left |g(x)-g(x-\frac{\pi}{n})\right|}_{=:h_n(x)}dx$$

Let's remind us that $g$ is piecewise constant, thus if $x$ and $x-\frac{\pi}{n}$ lie in the same constant piece, $h_n(x)=0$.

More precisely, let:

- $S:= \{ a \in [-\pi,\pi] : g \text{ changes value at } a\}$
- $S_n:= S+[0,\pi/n] $

If $x \not\in S_n$ ($x \in [-\pi,\pi]$) then $g_n(x)=0$ and $|S_n| \le \frac{\#S\pi}{n}$.
So let $C:= \max |g|$, from our previous result, we imply that:
$$|\hat{f}(n)| \le \frac{1}{2n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\#S\pi}{n} 2C
$$
Thus $$|\hat{f}(n)| \le \frac{D}{n^2}$$.

for all $n$, for some constant $D>0$
Hence forth the conclusion.

$\square$